# How to use preg_match better

Tags: preg-match

So i have been trying to build a script that basically pulls from a txt file a list.

Now the list is not the issue. Its more so the alg. im using

so for example.

if one 1 device the output is ABC(R)1234   i am using a preg match for look up ABC and then cut from ) and take the 1234 which is what i need.

BUT i just noticed another device, output ABC 1234 so my cut is not going to work.

i can do 2 preg_matchs like so

preg_match('/ABC/',$match){ etc right?

BUT thats for my cut..

so then i said well why dont i do a preg match for ABC(R) and ABC?

well it doesnt like (R) .. how can i match up a preg_match for ABC(R) and ABC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a part of regex optional with `?` quantifier. Like this:

```
$pattern = '/ABC(?:\([^)]+\))?\s*/';
```

Here `([^)]+)` part (which reads as 'match an opening parenthesis, then anything that's not a closing one, then a closing one) is placed into a non-capturing group (with `(?:...)`) notation, that has `?` quantifier sticked to it. In other words, it will capture all the matched text if it matches, but won't even notice if it's not there.

You can use it with `preg_replace` to cut these parts off ([demo](http://ideone.com/clone/fib2y6)):

```
$test1 = 'ABC(R)1234';
$test2 = 'ABC 5678';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $test1), PHP_EOL; // 1234
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $test2), PHP_EOL; // 5678
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. of course i changed it around a bit to fit my needs but thank you!